# json value and use it as search suggestion

Tags: java, android, json

Is there a way for me to get the value of `vehicle` arraylist and show it as search suggestion here? I am getting a null pointer value..

Main Activity

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Create the search view
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setQueryHint("What is your vehicle plate no.?");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
        String container = "";
        if (mSuggestionsAdapter == null) {
            MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);

//            ah = vehicle;
            for (int i = 0; i < ah.size(); i++) {
                container = container + ah.toString();
                String is = String.valueOf(i);
                cursor.addRow(new String[]{is, ah.get(0).get("plate_num").toString()});
            }

            mSuggestionsAdapter = new SuggestionsAdapter(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), cursor);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, vehicle.get(0).get("plate_num").toString() + "A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mSuggestionsAdapter);


        menu.add("Search")
                .setIcon(true ? R.drawable.ic_action_action_search : R.drawable.ic_action_action_search)
                .setActionView(searchView)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

        return true;
    }

    mSuggestionsAdapter = new SuggestionsAdapter(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), cursor);
```

On `VehicleFragment` on another class where I am getting the value. I declare `vehicle` as public static and get this variable.

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> vehicle;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


private class GetVehicles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        String plate_num = "",
                gps_num = "",
                location = "",
                date = "",
                time = "",
                lat = "",
                lng = "",
                engine = "",
                remarks = "";

            try {
                JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                vehicle = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i=0;i<jsonStr.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jr.getJSONObject(i);
                    plate_num = jb.getString("plate_num");
                    gps_num = jb.getString("gps_num");
                    location = jb.getString("location");
                    date = jb.getString("date");
                    time = jb.getString("time");
                    lat = jb.getString("lat");
                    lng = jb.getString("lng");
                    engine = jb.getString("engine");
                    remarks = jb.getString("remarks");

                    // tmp hash map for detail [single]
                    HashMap<String, String> details = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    details.put("plate_num", plate_num);
                    details.put("gps_num", gps_num);
                    details.put("location", location);
                    details.put("date", date);
                    details.put("time", time);
                    details.put("lat", lat);
                    details.put("lng", lng);
                    details.put("engine", engine);
                    details.put("remarks", remarks);

                    a = details.get("date");

                    // adding vehicle to vehicle list
                    vehicle.add(details);
                }
```

Comment: The way you're accessing vahicle object is not right. It will give you null value. Can you provide the MainActivity class!

Comment: It's hard to help when your code makes no sense and your description is not very descriptive.

Comment: Hi Hassa. Pls. check above updated code. Thanks